# AddThis Facebook preview - Image shared is not the latest image

Tags: facebook, widget, addthis

For some reasons the addthis widget on my page is not sharing the latest image - which can be deceiving.

This is the one example of the page - http://www.starbucks.com.sg/menu/beverages/chocolate-black-tea-double-chocolate-green-tea-frappuccino

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook and many other services use Open Graph meta tags to know which image should be shared, along with the title and description.

Here's some more information on Open Graph tags:
http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381222-optimize-facebook-sharing

Since the page you mentioned already has og:title and og:description meta tags, you'll just need to add og:url and og:image.

The Facebook Debugger tool is also a great tool for determining which OG tags Facebook is currently detecting and it can also "rescrape" a page to pick up newly added meta tags.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.starbucks.com.sg%2Fmenu%2Fbeverages%2Fchocolate-black-tea-double-chocolate-green-tea-frappuccino